# how to open a uialertview just before exit app manually in ios?

Tags: ios

I want to show this alert view just before when user exit app manually by clicking home button . I tried it by writing it in to did enter background delegate but its not showing.

**Code**

```
UIAlertView *rating  = [[ UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Rate Our App" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Never",@"Not Now",@"Later", nil];

[rating show];
```

Answer (score 0):

That will not work. You cannot delay the app from moving to the background.

> Use this method to release shared resources, invalidate timers, and store enough app state information to restore your app to its current state in case it is terminated later.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Got it backwards. Do it the other way around, show this alert every time  app launches. One cannot delay app closing or displaying interactive pop-ups when an app goes in background.

However, You can run non-interactive background tasks for 10 mins max to cleanup temp files, download something in the background etc. But those are all non-interactive user actions.

On a side note if you need a cool control that rates your app on app launch then try this [SARate](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sarate)